# executing a php shell script from a php web script is not working

Tags: php, shell

I have a php script (test.php) that has this in it:

```
<?php
exec("/usr/bin/php /path/to/myscript.php",$out);
print_r($out);
?>
```

When i try to run this script from the command line it works fine

```
> php test.php
```

and `myscript.php` simply returns "OK". However when i invoke `test.php` from the browser i get a strange nested array for $out as if myscript.php has been called recursively many times. Here is the warning i get:

```
exec(): Unable to fork [/usr/bin/php myscript.php] in test.php on line 3
```

Is there any way i can execute php from php like this?

Comment: I think this should be an issue with your hosting provider that has some kind of limitations to allow you to execute processes